# Why ajax like button in django is going crazy?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I've created a vanilla like button. It worked fine, but refreshes were really annoying, so I decided to implement ajax. It works kinda well, but I forced to update the page by myself to view the changes, cause I use `<script></script>` outside of the  `for post in posts` loop. In case I include it inside the loop, like counter is going crazy and update ALL posts on the page with reversed like/unlike state. Maybe, somebody will point my mistake.

posts/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create_post'),
    path('like/', like_view, name='like_post'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_post'),
]
```

posts/view.py

```
def like_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)

    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    if is_ajax(request):
        html = render_to_string('like_template.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

post_inclde.html AND ajax script.

This html file I include in the user profile page and in the feed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "like_post" request.user.slug %}',
      data: {
            'post_id': pk,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(response){
              $('#like_section_{{ post.id }}').html(response['form'])
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
              console.log(rs.responseText);
            },
          });
      crossDomain: false
     });
})
</script>

{% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card mb-3 border-0 shadow">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
            {{ post.body|safe }}
        </div>
        {% include 'like_template.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

like_template.html

```
<div id="like_section_{{ post.id }}">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.author.slug %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if request.user in post.likes.all %}
                <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                        style="border-radius: 60px;">
                    <img src="{% static 'icons/heartbreak-fill.svg' %}" alt="Unlike Icon" width="16" height="16"> {{ post.total_likes }}
                </button>
                {% else %}
                <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                        style="border-radius: 60px;">
                    <img src="{% static 'icons/heart-fill.svg' %}" alt="Like Icon" width="16" height="16"> {{ post.total_likes }}
                </button>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
            <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-2"
                    style="border-radius: 60px;" onclick="hide_comments('comment_section_{{ post.id }}')">
                <img src="{% static 'icons/chat-fill.svg' %}" alt="Post Comments Icon" width="16" height="16"> {{ post.comments.count }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: id `#like` is not unique on your page which is not good. And you don't have to attach onclick handler dynamically, finding elements by id. Try to write it as you do with `hide_comments` event handler and pass post_id as an argument just as you do with `hide_comments`. No need to put ajax function inside the loop. And here `$('#like_section_{{ post.id }}')` it should be `pk`, not `post.id`.

Comment: Could you share your models, so we can easily reproduce the issue?